# Create a list with text from another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file

I'm trying to add items to a list that are from another file.

This is what I have so far:

```
book_list = open("books.txt")
book_titles = []
```

I have no clue where to go from here.
The book titles in the text file each have their own line.
Can someone please resolve me of my ignorance? Thank you

Comment: How does the data in this file books.txt exist?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.split()` function and split by each new line!

```py
book_list = open("books.txt")
books_titles = book_list.read().split("\n")
```